# Within how many blocks do I have to be for wheat to grow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am planing on making an automated wheat farm as described in SyrupHut's tutorial. I am wanting to know within how many blocks of the wheat farm I have to be in order for it to keep growing. Does elevation make any difference? Running Minecraft 1.2.5 on a Survival Multiplayer server on Hard Difficulty, 50.56.92.111.

Comment: Aside from the range others discuss below, light up your farm.  Wheat doesn't grow at night if the light levels below 9.  https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Light

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to look at [this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Talk:Tutorials/Wheat_farming/Archive_1#Wheat_Not_Growing), specifically "Wheat Not Growing."

It looks like the only distance from (any) player that matters is the essentially the view distance since the area has to be loaded for the wheat to grow.

According to the [Chunks Minecraft page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunks), "In multiplayer mode, a grid with a default radius of 10 (for a total of 21x21 or 441 chunks) is loaded around each player and sent to the player by default, although this radius can be configured to be between 3 and 15, usually only lowered with a poor connection home server. These chunks may have activity (mobs spawning, trees growing, water flowing, dropped items disappearing etc.)"

Comment: A default server will have 10. However the server operator can change this at will, so you will have to experiment or ask the admin.

Comment: So, if I log onto the server and see my wheat, if I oam and my wheat is out of field of view, will my wheat still grow? And do I have to be within line of sight or can other player bea and it will still grow?

Comment: As long as any player is within range of your wheat, line of sight or not, the wheat should grow according to those two pages. I'm at work so I can't personally test this, but if you have a friend or two who can help you out I'd give it a shot. If things work as expected don't forget to accept my answer! ;)

Answer (score -2):

It grows better closer but 10 is the absolute limit

Comment: Hi Polly, and welcome to Arqade! It looks to me like your post would be better suited as an addendum to Chris'. Once you have enough [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), you'll be able to [write comments on other posts](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: It doesn't grow better when you're closer. Wheat grows when it receives a random "tick" from the game engine. These random ticks don't care how close you are, as long as the chunk is loaded.

Comment: "Better closer" probably means that if you're about 9-10 chunks away, the chunk may go in and out of the loaded state, slowing rates on a farm. (meaning the farm is not properly placed near a high-traffic area, or that your base is too far from the farm :)