# How does simulation-distance (a new 1.18 setting) effects chunk loading distance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Before 1.18 there was a rule for chunk loading distance that said "the chunk loading distance is equal to the view-distance" (you can read this [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk#Ticket_types) page at the section "player ticket").

The same is answered in this [reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/8vm897/question_regarding_chunk_loadingrender_distance/) or this Stackoverflow question about [chunk update radius](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150329/what-is-the-chunk-update-radius-in-single-player-minecraft?rq=1)

But since 1.18 there is a new config setting called "simulation-distance".
I already know that this setting effects in what range entities and liquids will be loaded and calculated, so that is not the question.

But I wonder if or how this new setting affects the chunk loading distance.

e.g. if settings are:

```
view-distance=5
simulation-distance=10
```

What will be the chunk loading distance (will it be 5, 10 or something else)?

or with

```
view-distance=10
simulation-distance=5
```

The wiki about [server.properties](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties#Java_Edition_3) does yust say `[more information needed]` for simulation distance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fully sure on what it does either, but to my knowledge, it loads the chunks in the simulation distance range, but does not load models. This can save a bit of resources if you don't have a (good) GPU.
So Mojang basically split the rendering process into two bits:

- Loading models and visuals (`view-distance` or render distance)
- Loading physics and entity movement (`simulation-distance`)

Whichever is the highest will determine how many chunks you load, but having simulation distance lower than `view-distance` while having things outside of that range is very interesting (but ultimately quite useless). Entities will stop moving the moment they cross the `simulation-distance` border, and water will stop flowing if it flows outside of this border.
If you have a lower end PC or laptop without a GPU, make sure to set your `view-distance` low. However, if you would still like to load things, just set your `simulation-distance` slightly higher than the `view-distance`.

Hope this clears stuff up! Again, this is what I can tell from watching some stuff on YouTube and testing around myself. Maybe this is inaccurate!

Comment: That was, what i way guessing, but I hoped somebody would have more accourate information.

Comment: [@ShadeOfLight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/263457/shadeoflight)

I made some tests... it seems that `simulation-distance` seems to have abolut no effect on chunk loading.

I tried it in singleplay, and with lowest `view-distance` and 24 chunks `simulation-distance` the world is still only chunks in view-distance.

And in opposide-test lowest `simulation-distance` and 24 chunks `view-distance` the world loads 24 chunks arround the player.

But I still would hope if anybody could offer an official answer from mojang, or from minecraft sourcecode.