# Keeping chunks loaded in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have built an iron farm somewhere far away from my actual spawn chunks in my single player world. In hindsight, this was a dumb idea, but I can't exactly change it anymore. I'd like to keep the thing running all the time, so I'm looking for a way to keep the chunks loaded.

I'm running minecraft 1.12.1, is it possible at the moment? I have looked at some chunk loader mods, but chicken chunk loader hasn't been updated yet, and the others simply didn't work.

I have tried moving the spawn chunks, but that hasn't done anything either.

Edit: I have worked this out with IronAnvil, and it ended up being a render setting in optifine which didn't load them correctly somehow. It has been working fine after I reset my optifine settings to default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are ok with setting the spawn chunks, I recommend that as the easiest solution.

The command: `setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>`.

One thing to note from [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setworldspawn):

> Although spawn chunks are usually kept loaded at all times, new spawn chunks won't be loaded by this command until a player moves within range. Compasses (which in Minecraft point to the world spawn rather than north) will also not update to the change until the world is reloaded.

Comment: But does that not mean that once I set the new world spawn, the chunks won't be loaded anyway?

Comment: What the wiki is stating is that you have to go to those new spawn chunks to load them in the first place.  I personally would go stand near your iron farm and type `/setworldspawn` in chat.  Then save and quit, and reopen.  It should stay loaded whenever you are playing after that.

Comment: Alright I'll try it out. I'll let you know!

Comment: Unrelated, but if you need a lot of iron for some reason, there are several fast producing designs.  You can also stack the smaller ones.  [Here is the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming) on iron golem farming if you are interested.

Comment: Well I already built the iron phoenix from tango tek, which has cost me quite some time and resources... I'd prefer that thing to work all the first, then I'll jump to alternatives :P

Comment: Oh.  OK.  One thing to note on that design, from what I have heard, when they unload, all the villages will combine.  I imagine that is why you asked this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if they combine, but it does stop working when it unloads. That's why I want it to keep running all the time, yeah. That way I can afk at my exp farm (or do something else in general), while my iron farm is still running

Comment: I have tested it, and somehow it still unloads the chunks for me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65351/discussion-between-ironanvil-and-anonymousperson).

Answer (score 13):

Good news, everyone! [Minecraft 1.13.1](https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-1131-released) added this feature:

> Added a concept of force-loaded chunks to the game, and a command ([`/forceload`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/forceload)) to toggle force-loading on and off

[Wikilink mine.]

So now you don't need to keep your mob farms and such near spawn just to keep them loaded, and maybe the fancy mechanism that animates the light in your lighthouse will work reliably even for players with insane draw distances, too.

Caveat: according to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk#Not_Processed), plants don't grow just because a chunk is loaded; they have to be within some distance: the render distance in single-player, and some server parameter in multiplayer. According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/260330), that parameter is called `view-distance`.

Comment: Nice answer, would be even better with an example command.

Comment: Find the block coordinates (not chunk coordinates) of the northwest and southeast corners of the area you want loaded. You can use coordinates from any block in the chunks you want to start and end in. For example I want to force load all chunks from blocks x=22 z=178 to x=101 z=298. I use this command: `/forceload add 22 178 101 298`. You can stop loading those chunks with the command `/forceload remove 22 178 101 298`, or `/forceload remove all`. If you just want to load the chunk you are standing in then use `/forceload add ~ ~`.

Comment: @JesseHallett You can suggest an edit to add that.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a chunk loader. But keep in mind that they are abusing bugs that could get fixed in the future and that they will increase lag.

[This design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeq5GZxRH9s) works without connecting it to the spawn chunks, but you have to load it manually again after every restart of Minecraft.

[This design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIDHfxApRMQ) requires to be connected to the spawn chunks, but it gets automatically loaded when you join the world.

Comment: Remark: I wrote this after reading a previous version of the question. If you're ok with moving the spawn chunks, that's of course way easier.

Comment: I learned from your answer, so I am still glad you posted it.

Comment: Both could work, but I'm looking for something that keeps them loaded all the time, without having to turn it on/off. I tried moving the spawn point, but it hasn't done anything, sadly. Still both good solutions though!

Comment: What do you get when you use this tool? http://chunkbase.com/apps/spawn-chunks-reader Are the spawn chunks around your new spawn point?

Comment: Update for 1.14: Chunk loading is completely broken. Not just machines like the ones I linked here, also `/forceload`, spawn chunks, regular redstone lines and so on. Nothing loads chunks properly anymore, except for a player being near.

Answer (score -2):

One good option available for you is to log on to the single player world. in that, pressing escape key will show you to select "open to lan". After that you will get chat message that server was hosted in Port ####.

Now login to mine craft from another account. Join the world with your pc's ip:Port number. And after logging in let the other profile do afk session near the iron farm

Comment: Excuses, it's single player. But again? This is my first post where I made that error..

Comment: Why would you make so difficult? You don't need to make it a multiplayer world to load chunks.