# Loading and unloading Minecart, Distance issues?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have built a loader and unloader with chests in minecarts based on [this design](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/345199-extremley-compact-minecart-loader-unloader). I have tested my redstone circuits and track etc over a short distance and all works lovely. But when I move the unloader approximately 600 railtracks away it doesn't seem to be working. When I am around the minecart it seems to do what it is ment to. But if I wait with the unloader for the minecart to come back it doesn't happen.

Do I have to stay near the minecart for this to work? Surely not.

Comment: Are you just talking about loading and unloading minecarts with chests?  Please elaborate on your setup and the issue you're having.

Comment: Hello, This is the set up I copied. http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/345199-extremley-compact-minecart-loader-unloader

Comment: The minecart only seems to load and unload when i am in close proximity to the loader/unloader. The minecart has no worries travelling the route.

Comment: Okay, I thoughts that's what you meant, but I couldn't be sure.

Comment: I have only being playing minecraft for a couple of weeks so i'm still a baby. I'm trying to research and come across a term called 'chunks.' Could this have something to do with it? I'm not exactly sure what chunks are.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what's going on; the chunks at the other end of your rail line aren't loaded, so your device isn't doing anything. A chunk is simply an area of the map that's 16 blocks by 16 blocks. Minecraft will only load so many chunks around you. I'd give a more complete answer if I wasn't already in bed.

Answer (score 3):

You are too far away for the system to work properly.  The chunks are not loaded.

As you walk around, you are loading and unloading chunks at a specific distance from yourself.  In single player, the view distance determines that specific distance.  Normal view distance is 8 chunks.

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk):

> The exact number of generated chunks varies in single player mode, depending on view distance and movement.
>
> Chunks within the set range may have activity (mobs spawning, trees growing, water flowing, dropped items disappearing etc.), while chunks outside of this range are inactive, and are stored on the disk (this 'store until needed' memory management is commonly used with procedurally-generated terrain so that the players' computers don't have to track and update hundreds of plants and mobs simultaneously).

600 blocks is equal to 37.5 chunks which is above the view distance maximum.  The train cart stops functioning once it reaches these unloaded chunks.  Then as you walk down the track you are loading those chunks so the train cart goes back to functioning the way you expect it to.

One possible solution is to use a chunk loader design which purposefully prevents the out of range chunks from unloading.  [Here is an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317916/186522) to another question with a couple of designs to do that.